/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1 on centos
[nobin@CentOS9 tc-dump]$ CGO_ENABLED=1 go build
# github.com/Asphaltt/tc-dump
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lresolv
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


OS specs:
[nobin@CentOS9 tc-dump]$ uname -a
Linux CentOS9 4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 22 00:20:22 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[nobin@CentOS9 tc-dump]$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="8 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="8"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 8 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:8"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-8"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="8"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8"

I'm trying to compile a code. On my host ubuntu machine it compiles correctly. But one CentOS machine. It throws the following error, when invoked with CGO_ENABLED=1 go build
After trying to install the required packages I get these errors:
Updated:
[nobin@CentOS9 tc-dump]$ sudo yum install glibc-static
CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                                                                                          6.3 kB/s | 7.9 kB     00:01    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'AppStream':
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 50.2.190.74)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
CentOS-8 - Base                                                                                                                                               5.5 kB/s | 7.9 kB     00:01    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'BaseOS':
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 69.167.138.255)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'BaseOS': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
Ignoring repositories: AppStream, BaseOS
Last metadata expiration check: 0:28:42 ago on বৃহস্পতিবার 04 এপ্রিল 2024 04:52:13 পূর্বাহ্ণ UTC.
No match for argument: glibc-static
Error: Unable to find a match: glibc-static

[nobin@CentOS9 tc-dump]$ sudo yum install libpthread-stubs 
CentOS-8 - AppStream                                                                                                                                          5.1 kB/s | 7.9 kB     00:01    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'AppStream':
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/AppStream/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 104.206.99.122)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'AppStream': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
CentOS-8 - Base                                                                                                                                               7.0 kB/s | 7.9 kB     00:01    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'BaseOS':
  - Status code: 404 for http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 192.240.166.165)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'BaseOS': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
Ignoring repositories: AppStream, BaseOS
Last metadata expiration check: 0:29:39 ago on বৃহস্পতিবার 04 এপ্রিল 2024 04:52:13 পূর্বাহ্ণ UTC.
No match for argument: libpthread-stubs
Error: Unable to find a match: libpthread-stubs


I solved it. I had to enable the PowerTools.
dnf config-manager --enable PowerTools
dnf --enablerepo=powertools install glibc-static
dnf --enablerepo=powertools install libpthread-stubs

I also did edits on enabled=0 instead of 1
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-AppStream.repo


your linker is not able to find these libraries. Try installing these packages, it should solve the issue:
sudo yum check-update
sudo yum install -y glibc-static 
sudo yum install -y libpthread-stubs 

I am not very sure if these are the actual packages, but try related package if not, I dont have permission to comment yet, so comment on my answer before downvoting.

I've added the output after running these commands on main post above

This seems yum is not working on your machine, which vrsion of centOS you are using?
